# Select row in dataframe based on row in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

#### Problem

I want to retrieve a value in `df2` based on the *value of the first row and first column* in `df1`.

The first row and first column in df1 has to match a value in the *second column in df2*.

I'm unsure how this can be done with R.

```
x1 <- rep(9:40)
x2 <- seq(32, 1, by = -1)
df1 <- data.frame(x1, x2)

y1 <- seq(10)
y2 <- seq(153, 0, by = -16)
df2 <- data.frame(y1,y2)
```

#### Expected Output

```
# df1[1, 1] == 9 and 
# df2[10, 2] == 9,
# therefore

> df2[10, 1]
[1] 10
```

Comment: You might have forgotten to add y3 to the question.

Comment: Any chance you have your x's and y's mixed up?

Comment: Could you define `df1` and `df2` beforehand? If you look at your code, you'll see `df1` is defined before `y1`, `y2` or `y3` are defined. In fact, `y3` is literally never defined at all.

Comment: Apologies copied the wrong sample data I had generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straightforward:

```
df2[df2$y2 == df1[1, 1], 1]
```

#### Data

```
x1 <- 9:40
x2 <- 32:1
df1 <- data.frame(x1, x2)

y1 <- 1:10
y2 <- seq(153, 0, by = -16)
df2 <- data.frame(y1, y2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question because the answer I'm going to give us is quite easy.
What if you call the 'cell' present at the intersection between the first row and the first column of `df1` :`df1[1,1]`.

Then, I'd just call it in the way `df2[df1[1,1],1]`

Did I miss something?